# Forcing a call to a Django view method using POST instead of GET

Tags: django

I have a Django view method (lets call it Method A) with some response for `GET` and some other response for `POST`. If Method A is called via `POST`, it displays a HTML page which contains a form.

Once the user submits this form, the form calls another method (Method B) in `views.py` which checks whether the form is valid. If the form contains errors, I want to go back to the previous page and display the error.

How do I "go back to the previous page"? Or what I'm basically asking is this - From Method B, how do I call Method A using `POST` so that my previous HTML page with the form gets displayed again?

Please assume I'm not using Django forms.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a redirection on POST error back to the page itself them along with some info about the error message for display. Otherwise, I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this but I'm sure you have a good reason :)